# CodeIgniter - how to access base_url() in a helper?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm extending URL helper (MY_url_helper). How do I access base_url() within my helper function? I'm actually overriding base_url(), so I need to call the original base_url.

**Edit 1:**

This doesn't work:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->helper('url');
$base_url = $CI->base_url();
```

Comment: simply define a method base_url it will be overridden

Comment: @Gautam3164 - I want to use base_url().

Comment: @raheelshan - my question is not about overriding. it's about accessing base_url() function from a function that is trying to override the original function.

Comment: in your extended library create an instance of ci $this->ci = $get_instance(); then $this->ci->load->helper('url'); Done!

Comment: `$this` does not work in helpers. But I know how to create an instance of CI and load a helper (though I shouldn't need to since it's already autoloaded in my application). How do you call base_url() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately built-in helper functions are defined in the global php namespace, once you define a function with a name `base_url` you won't be able to define another one with the same name, so you can't load the original `base_url` function from the original helper "somwehere else" and use it.

For this reason CI's built-in helper files define function in if blocks like this:

```
if ( ! function_exists('FUNCTION_NAME'))
// ...
}
```

so even if you load the original helper file in your overridden version it doesn't create a fatal error, but also doesn't do anything meaningful.

In your concrete case, the base_url's implementation is basically a:

```
return get_instance()->config->base_url($uri);
```

you can lift it into your overridden version of `base_url`.